# If time was non-existent would we be able to move?

Tags: kinematics, time

If time would stop, would we be able to move, or would we be "frozen"? also if we could move, would we be able to move at a infinite speed ?

Comment: What does "move" even mean without the concept of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely under the impression time is this sort of thing that stands on its own, which it sort of does in your everyday experience. If you're just sitting there in your chair, time keeps moving. It's "something else", compared to the change in location. You move through your room, but you don't think about moving through time.

But that is actually wrong.

What follows is a toy model, but it will illustrate the issue.

Think about a really large balloon. Really large. Like 14 billion light-years across. Now you know it's hard enough to see the curvature of the Earth while on the surface right? So I think you can imagine that if you lived on the surface of this 14 bly balloon, it would look flat.

Good so far?

Ok, now what if that balloon were slowly inflating? How would you know? There would be no obvious change to the things around you. The difference in location from minute to minute would be much less than the size of an atom. In order to notice it, you'd have to look at things that were further away. Like another galaxy. And then you'd notice they were slowly moving away from you. They're not really moving, I guess, it's just that the balloon you're all sitting on is stretching out so the space between you is getting larger.

Still with me?

Ok, now let's call one direction on the surface of the balloon X and another Y. Now we will label the remaining direction, the one from the centre of the balloon out to its surface -its radius- as "time".

So now let's say you move from (1,1) to (2,2) on the surface of the balloon. Notice that even though you didn't say it, you also moved through time, because the balloon is inflating. In fact, even if you just sit at (1,1), guess what, you're still moving through time because the balloon is inflating.

That balloon *is* expanding, its called "the universe". And we really do see things far away, like galaxies, moving away from us. What we don't see is that "other direction", the time direction. Well we do, your watch keeps changing for instance, but we don't *see* it like we see, say, height. We don't interpret it in our brain that way, even though that's exactly what it is.

Ok, back to your original question, if there is no time, is there motion? Well, time is a dimension, and if there's no time, that means the universe is zero size. Is there motion in a zero-size universe?

The answer should now be obvious.